# Polymer "animate" function no longer working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, polymer, web-animations

Paper-dialog uses entry/exit animations but Chrome deprecated this function.

Is there a work around??? Do I need to update web-animations-js?

```
<paper-dialog id="help" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation" without-backdrop>
```

I get the following error on a page that has an animation after I try to click:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': 'function (a){return a}' is not a valid value for easing(…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update web-animations-js.

https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js/releases

try use 2.2.1 version.

Comment: Yep. We had to re-download from Polymer. Solved everything. Thanks friend